# What is the cause of "SSL Library Error: error:0A000076:SSL routines::no suitable signature algorithm" from upgrading Apache24 from 2.4.55 to 2.4.58?

Tags: algorithm, apache, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

This is my first question here so apologies if I lack any details.

I have a web app that is running on Apache 2.4.55 and OpenSSL 1.1.1t. I made a backup of the Apache24 folder, downloaded the binary files for Apache 2.4.58, and overwrote the files in the Apache24 folder with the newer version. I then overwrote the httpd-ssl.conf and httpd.conf files to keep the original settings for the app. I was able to access the app via browser in my current desktop but when repeating the same method in a client's desktop, I was unable to access it on the browser. In the error.log file, it said the following:

```
AH02008: SSL library error 1 in handshake (server v...:443)
SSL Library Error: error:0A000076:SSL routines::no suitable signature algorithm
```

I am back in my own desktop and have been trying to reproduce the error to find the cause.
I think it involves OpenSSL 1.1.1 using signature algorithms that are deprecated in OpenSSL 3.1.3, but I can't find what those algorithms are and how to change them.

Here are a few things I tried:

I currently have OpenSSL 3.1.4 in my OpenSSL-Win64. I downgraded it to OpenSSL 1.1.1t and made a certificate using that version, however using it did not lead to that error.

I tried changing the security settings in mozilla firefox to TLSver1.0, 1.1, and 1.2, but they led to the following error instead:

```
AH02008: SSL library error 1 in handshake (server ...:443)
SSL Library Error: error:0A000BF:SSL routines::no protocols available
```

I tried to change the security level directly in the openssl.cnf file:

```
openssl_conf = default_conf
...
[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=2
```

But there were no changes to any effect.